# bad usage on attempting to mount

Tags: mount, samba, nfs, shared-folders, cifs

I don't understand the bad usage that is happening here. I am trying to mount a samba share (NAS) and I get `mount: bad usage`. I was under the impression `mount` is used:

```
mount <options> <localtion to mount> <local place its mounted>
```

So I attempted to create that with this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER, password=PASSWORD //IPADRRESS:/homes /media/backups/
```

I got this from the man pages and the following references (I realize some are referencing NFS when I have stated I am using samba):

[1] https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Talk:Mounting_an_NFS_share_on_Ubuntu

[2] https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04

[3] https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: Don't put blanks after commas. `-o username=USER,password=PASSWORD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things I see:

1. You give link to a tutorial on `nfs` (Network File System) and not `CIFS` (Common Internet File System).
2. The format for `cifs` is:

   ```
   mount -t cifs //server-name/share-name /mnt/cifs -o username=USER,password=PASSWORD
   ```

   - No space as pointed out from previous answer, and
   - No `:` between IP address and share folder

So your mount command should be:

```
 sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USER,password=PASSWORD //IPADRRESS/homes /media/backups/
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a space in your options.  All of the -o options should not have any spaces between them.

Hope this helps